# How to efficiently Rank model obj in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model called 'Student' and it has a field 'score' that stores the total marks attained by  students. I would love to know a way that will enable me to rank students based on their respective scores. My concern here is if there is a way i can rank the students and output the value for each student in the detail view.
**In the list view, i used 'order_by('-score')' attribute and displayed their positions using {{ forloop.counter }} and the list view is working perfectly**.

```
class Student(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
score = models.IntergerField()


def __str__ (self):
    return f"{ self.name} - { self.score }"
```

Comment: What is a "rank"? What if two students have the same score?

Comment: I intend to assing students same rank if they have same score and skip one position.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Student.objects.order_by('score')
```

For more info about order_by: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Comment: this method works very well in the list view since it will order the items in desc/asc order. I can't use it to display the position of students in detail view

Comment: Hello, i solved the problem by using list.index() method. I created the function pasted below in the model and displayed the position in the detail view using {{ object.ranking }}

Comment: @property
    def ranking(self, *args, **kwargs):

        marks = Student.objects.all().values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('-score')
        rank = list(marks).index(self.pk)
        

        
        return rank